# QGIS 3.10.4-A Coruña processing.run overload?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a command block with multiple run.processing commands (`gdal:clipvectorbyextent`, `grass7:v.transform`, `native:dissolve`) in a loop `for` in PyQGIS.

Everything is fine at first, after executing a `for` loop multiple times I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 181, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
```

Is it possible to overload the `processing.run` algorithm?

Comment: 3.10.4 is old, more than a year old. I would first upgrade to 3.10.14 or 3.16.4 https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule Then, maybe you should share the code. Updating the code of processing.run looks not a so good idea I think. Maybe there is another issue ?

Comment: Thank you. I am working on linux mint. I will try to install a newer version of Qgis.  I ran the fragment of the algorithm in for loop with the same input. Errors occur randomly after a few minutes algorithm run.

Comment: In the QGIS logs, look also in every tab if there is something suspicious.